# ¿Cómo realizar tarea programada en Ubuntu con Python?

Tags: python, linux, cron

Tengo un script y me genera muchas dudas, ya que deseo crear una tarea programada en linux. estoy en el directorio :

```
/home/aa/Scripts/test
```

en este mismo directorio tengo todos los scripts que voy a ejecutar. Asimismo tengo otro script que llama a estos scripts :

```
import datetime
import os
import smtplib

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

if( os.system("python script1.py") !=0):enviarMail("script1")
if( os.system("python script2.py") !=0):enviarMail("script2")
if( os.system("python script3.py") !=0):enviarMail("script3")
if( os.system("python script4.py") !=0):enviarMail("script4")
if( os.system("python script5.py") !=0):enviarMail("script5")


end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print('Tarea programada finalizada en : {}'.format(end_time - start_time)[:-4])
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente..
Estuve investigando cron y crontab, y por lo que tengo entendido, se usan scripts con la terminación `.sh`. Si deseo ejecutar este `.py` cierto día de la semana.. tengo que cambiar de directorio a mi `script` ?. Sí esto implica moverlo a otro directorio, las llamadas a los otros scripts también deberían ser modificadas ya que al ejecutarlos por `os` solo escribo `python nombrescript.py`.
Espero haberme explicado bien, gracias por cualquier ayuda y recomendación,

Comment: Y porque no escribes ruta completa al script, asi no tienes que mover los otros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No tienes que cambiar el script de directorio, solo usa la ruta absoluta al mismo en el comando cuando añadas la nueva linea a crontab (`$ crontab -e`) por ejemplo:

```
0 13 * * 4 python /home/aa/Scripts/test/cron_mail.py
```

ejecuta el script `cron_mail.py` situado en `/home/aa/Scripts/test` cada jueves a las 13:00.

Puedes ser más explícito y especificar la ruta absoluta al intérprete, por ejemplo:

```
0 13 * * 4 /usr/bin/python /home/aa/Scripts/test/cron_mail.py
```

Lo que si debes hacer, tal como tienes las llamadas a `os.system` (con rutas relativas al directorio de trabajo actual y no absolutas) es cambiar el directorio de trabajo del script, para que sea el directorio dónde se encuentra el propio archivo. Claro está que en tu caso podrías especificar las rutas absolutas a cada script en las llamadas a `os.system`, no obstante, hay casos en los que es necesario cambiar el directorio de trabajo por otras raazones, por lo que obviaré esto en la respuesta.

La forma más obvia es hacerlo en el propio comando a ejecutar por cron:

```
0 13 * * 4 cd /home/aa/Scripts/test && python cron_mail.py
```

la otra opción es modificarlo en el propio script y usar en crontab el comando que muestro al principio:

```
import datetime
import os
import smtplib
import sys


os.chdir(sys.path[0]))

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# Resto
```

---

Aparte de esto, en vez de `crontab` yo prefiero en lo personal usa `systemd` para estos menesteres, en concreto podemos hacer uso de [systemd.timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html).

- Es  muy importante que primero añadas la linea de shebang adecuada como primera linea a tu script Python (el que va a lanzar systemd) para que sepa que intérprete ha de usarse para su ejecución, por ejemplo:

  ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
  ```

  Debes cambiarlo para adecuarlo a tu caso si es necesario, dependiendo de dónde esté le binario del intérprete Python que quieras que se use.
- Dar permisos de ejecución al script que quieres ejecutar periódicamente:

  ```
  $ chmod +x  /home/aa/Scripts/test/cron_mail.py
  ```
- Configuramos un nuevo servicio, al que llamaremos `mailBot`, empezando por crear el archivo `.service`:

  ```
  $ sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/mailBot.service
  $ sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/mailBot.service
  $ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mailBot.service
  ```

  El contenido del archivo sería algo así:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Python mail bot

  [Service]
  WorkingDirectory=/home/aa/Scripts/test 
  ExecStart=/home/aa/Scripts/test/cron_mail.py
  Restart=on-failure
  ```

  `WorkingDirectory` nos permite especificar el directorio de trabajo antes de lanzar el script, lo que resuelve tu problema incial de forma simple.
- Creamos el `.timer`:

  ```
  $ sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/mailBot.timer
  $ sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/mailBot.timer
  $ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mailBot.timer
  ```

  El contenido del archivo `mailBot.timer` sería algo así:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Python mail bot timer

  [Timer]
  OnCalendar=Thu *-*-* 13:00:00
  Persistent=true

  [Install]
  WantedBy=timers.target
  ```

  La clave para la programación temporal está en `OnCalendar=Thu *-*-* 13:00:00`, la sintaxis general es:

  ```
  dia_de_la_semana año-mes-dia hora:minutos:secgundos
  ```

  en este caso cada jueves, sin importar año mes o dia (`*`) a las 13 horas, 0 minutos, 0 segundos.
- Guardamos el archivo y recargamos

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
  ```
- Iniciamos el servicio y lo habilitar para que se inicie cuando lo haga el sistema automáticamente:

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl start mailBot.timer
  $ sudo systemctl enable mailBot.timer
  ```

Cierto que es más complejo que añadir una linea al archivo  crontab, pero es una herramienta muchísimo más potente que cron.

Si el inglés no es un problema, tienes una guía bastante buena de systemd en la wiki de ArchLinux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd

> **Nota**
>
> No tiene nada que ver con esto, pero `os.system` se considera una API anticuada, piensa en usar [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) en su lugar.

Comment: Excelente, lo voy a tener en cuenta ya que soy nuevo en esto. Muchas gracias