# automatización script python

Tags: python-3.x, servidor, script

hola tengo la siguiente duda, en el directorio que pueden ver 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

existen varias carpetas en ellas se encuentran documentos en formato pdf y quiero extraer las tablas que se encuentran en ellas por medio de python y las librerías tabula-py y camelot.

```
import tabula
tabula.convert_into("url","name.csv",pages="1,2")
```

eso lo logro con el siguiente código y quiero automatizar el proceso con un script que pueda ver los directorios y después transformar todas las tablas a csv un viernes por la noche como ejemplo.
Aquí mi dilema no tengo ni idea de como empezar

Comment: Te recomiendo buscar algún codigo referente a tu pregunta y colocarla en ella para mejor entendimiento y calificación de tu pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Saludos

Comment: Hola Fernando aparte de la recomendación más que apropiada de Miguel, si tu problema es simplemente la automatización de la ejecución temporal del script, mirate , [¿Cómo realizar tarea programada en Ubuntu con Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/265448/15089), puede ser de ayuda dependiendo del sistema operativo del servidor. systemd es perfecto para estos menesteres....

Comment: Lectura obligatoria https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822